# How to generate flat file multiple header from ssis?

Tags: ssis

Ho all,

I need to generate flat file that can have multiple header rows like below

```
Head|123|
Detail|qwe|123|234|aaa
Head|123|
Detail|qwe|123|234|aaa
Head|123|
Detail|qwe|123|234|aaa
```

How do I do this in ssis?

Comment: Your example shows a single row, not multiple?

Comment: Your example data is rather confusing, could you edit the question to explain what it should be doing? Seeing the sample you provided isn't what I would call multiple header rows. Also, since it's all the same data, we don't know if there's a relationship between each header line and the detail, what that relationship is, etc.